# How does kubectl interact with the k8s cluster(s)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I understand that `kubectl` is some kind of interface with a K8s cluster but I don't fully understand what's going on.
I see that tutorials mention various commands e.g.

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl decribe pod
```

etc

but I don't really understand with which nodes in the cluster does `kubectl` interact.
First of all in a production system is there only one k8s cluster or multiple?
How does kubectl know which cluster or which node to execute the commands we pass? Or does it do it for all cluster/nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions in one here.

- How does it know which cluster to interact with? That's the kubeconfig and context. `cat ~/.kube/config` — you should see at least one `context`, and a `current-context`.
- How many clusters might you have in prod? Depends on your system, I've had systems with 1, 2, and 3, but there could be many more (think about cross-region availability, separate clusters for compliance, isolation of internal applications, etc).
- How does it interact with clusters at all? The API, kubectl is essentially a nice CLI that hits kube-apiserver, which is exposed by the control plane to allow access to the cluster and its resources.

I highly recommend skimming [the glossary](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/) and reading about [the components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/), and spending some additional time with the docs in general, to get a feel for how all the pieces interact.

Comment: What is `context` and `current-context`? Is it the same as cluster?

Comment: A context is a combination of cluster, user you're accessing as, and namespace you're in (in that cluster). current-context is which one you've currently got selected — just switching clusters doesn't help you much because you also need to switch authentication between clusters, and for day-to-day usage it's usually more useful to be in a specific namespace by default rather than `kube-system` or `default` (for example, say I'm actively looking at an issue in the `datascience` namespace across dev and prod, I can do `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=datascience`)

Comment: So a cluster has many namespaces? What do these namespaces represent? pods? Also why is the user I am accessing as part of this combination?

Comment: I really recommend reading the two links I posted because it sounds like you're starting from the beginning (which is fine! but there are good docs and tutorials out there that explain better than I will). But in short, namespaces group resources (and allow you to reuse names, because you can't have two things called `foo-ingress` in the same namespace, but you can have a `foo-ingress` in two different namespaces). The user matters because you'll have different users for each cluster (you can also do this with more than one kubeconfig file, but it's no more convenient).

Answer (score 0):

kubectl is nothing but it actually sends curl requests to your server to perform an operation.
Kubectl is used as kubectl[command][type][name][flags]
where command can be get, delete, apply etc
type is an object of kubernetes like pod, service, namespace, statefulset etc.
name is the name of resource that you wish to query and flag is some flag like if you wish to see output in a particular format for e.g. -o yaml, -o json

When you execute a query in above format, it makes a request to the kube api server(curl in the backend) and gives a response.

It does this by, first authenticating with the Master Node and then making API calls to do a variety of management actions.